# Is it possible to just extract the SPARQL endpoint from a SPARQL query?

Tags: java, sparql, owl, endpoint

I'm learning Semantic Web programming and trying to develop an app for the Android platform. There's a textfield in my app where the user would enter a SPARQL query.

I was wondering if I could just extract the SPARQL endpoint from a whole SPARQL query. For example, in the query `SELECT ?class FROM <http://myexample.com> WHERE{?class a owl:Class} Order By ?class` I would want to extract the `http://myexample.com`.

Or from a query that looks like `SELECT ?dataType ?data WHERE { <http://nasa.dataincubator.org/launch/1961-012> ?dataType ?data.}` , extract the `http://nasa.dataincubator.org/launch/1961-012`.

I want to use the extracted endpoint and then retrieve the classes, properties, etc. of that ontology from within the SPARQL endpoint.

Is it possible to extract just the endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to extract the URI `http://myexample.com/` from your example query. Either parse the query and inspect the parse result (how you do this depends on what query parser you use), or just write a simple regex that grabs the `FROM` clause and extract the URI behind it.

However, the URI in the `FROM` clause is **not** the SPARQL endpoint. The `FROM` clause in a SPARQL query specifies a *named graph*, which, very generally speaking, is a subset of the total dataset over which you're querying. But it doesn't tell you what SPARQL endpoint the query will be executed by.

In general, the SPARQL endpoint is not part of the query itself, but is determined by the tool you use to actually execute the query.

There is one case in which you *can* determine the endpoint used from the query itself, and that is if the SPARQL query uses a `SERVICE` clause, for example:

```
SELECT *
WHERE { 
   SERVICE <http://example.org/sparql> { ?s ?p ?o } 
}
LIMIT 100
```

But this construction is not guaranteed to be used, and in fact the majority of SPARQL queries don't use it.